# R programming - missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed : for loop

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, boolean

demo is the name of the dataset. Salary.Slab is the name of the variable. 
I am using if else statement inside for loop to create buckets.

```
head(demo$Salary.Slab)
[1]  5  7  1  6 NA NA
```

There are some missing values in the column. I am aware of the fact that if statement does not work with NA values, hence  I have written the following code using is.na

```
for( i in nrow(demo))
{
if(is.na(demo$Salary.Slab[i])){
demo$salary = "k"

}else  if(demo$Salary.Slab[i] == 1){
demo$salary = "Very Low"

}else if(demo$Salary.Slab[i] == 3) {
demo$salary = "Very Low"

}else if(demo$Salary.Slab[i] == 4){
demo$salary = "Low"

}else if(demo$Salary.Slab[i] == 5){
demo$salary = "Low"

}else if(demo$Salary.Slab[i] == 6){
demo$salary = "Low"
}
}
```

salary is the new variable I am creating to store values of buckets ("very low", "low", etc...)

But when I run the above code I am getting all "k" values in each row. Whereas I should get "k" only in places where Salary.Slab = NA and "very low" where Salary.slab == 1 and so on.  Please tell where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Should it be `demo$salary[i]` instead of `demo$salary` every time?

Comment: Your conditions are fine, but the assignments you have, e.g., `demo$salary = "k"`, assign the whole vector, not the `i`th element. As Andrey says, add `[i]` to the assignment lines. Or see `ifelse` for a vectorized method.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a shorter solution:

```
# Vector of numbers or NAs
Salary.Slab = c( 5,  7,  1,  6, NA, NA)

# bin by threshold
ind = findInterval(Salary.Slab, c(0,4))

# deal with missing values (number of bins plus 1)
ind[is.na(ind)] = 3;

# Assign names by bin
salary = c('Very Low', 'Low', 'k')[ind]

# Here is the result:
salary

[1] "Low"      "Low"      "Very Low" "Low"      "k"        "k"       

# Combined with the original vector
cbind(Salary.Slab, salary)

     Salary.Slab salary    
[1,] "5"         "Low"     
[2,] "7"         "Low"     
[3,] "1"         "Very Low"
[4,] "6"         "Low"     
[5,] NA          "k"       
[6,] NA          "k"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to subset the result of the if/then :

```
for( i in 1:nrow(demo))
{
  if(is.na(demo$Salary.Slab[i])){
    demo$salary[i] = "k"

  }else  if(demo$Salary.Slab[i] == 1){
    demo$salary[i] = "Very Low"

  }else if(demo$Salary.Slab[i] == 3) {
    demo$salary[i] = "Very Low"

  }else if(demo$Salary.Slab[i] == 4){
    demo$salary[i] = "Low"

  }else if(demo$Salary.Slab[i] == 5){
    demo$salary[i] = "Low"

  }else if(demo$Salary.Slab[i] == 6){
    demo$salary[i] = "Low"
  }
}
```

Otherwise, it assigns a single value to the whole column.

Comment: I don't think he must add explicitly somthing about the is.na() == TRUE. `is.na(demo$Salary.Slab[i])` already returns a boolean.

Comment: Still the same thing happening.

Comment: Well, I ran it multiple times and get the desired results.  Note: you have a 7 in the dataset, but no 7 option in the loop.

Comment: @RyanMorton - Could you please explain me clearly what do you men by subset the result of if/then ? Actually,  i have just mentioned few if else statements here , its similar through out.

Comment: `demo$salary[i] = "k"` has the [i] subsetting the results for just that row.

Comment: @RyanMorton - Thanks a lot. Working now :)